# Creating LBP histogram

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision

I have been able to implement a basic local binary pattern (LBP), without interpolation. Following is the code: **(OpenCV)**

```
int center = 0;   
int center_lbp = 0;   

for (int row = 1; row < Image.rows; row++)   
{
  for (int col = 1; col < Image.cols; col++)   
  {   
    center = Image.at<int>(row, col);
    center_lbp = 0;   

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row-1, col-1) )   
      center_lbp += 1;   

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row-1, col) )   
      center_lbp += 2;   

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row-1, col+1) )   
      center_lbp += 4;   

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row, col-1) )   
      center_lbp += 8;   

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row, col+1) )   
      center_lbp += 16;   

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row+1, col-1) )   
      center_lbp += 32;   

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row+1, col) )   
      center_lbp += 64;

    if ( center <= Image.at<int>(row+1, col+1) )   
      center_lbp += 128;   

    cout << "center lbp value: " << center_lbp << endl;
    LBPImage.at<int>(row, col) = center_lbp;
  }
}
```

Read lot of things...but can't figure out how to create histogram now with uniform patterns concept...did check few links...nothing much there....can anybody please help...

thanks!

Comment: Judging by the tags you included, you are using opencv or thinking of using it. If you have, a simple google search of 'opencv histogram' may be of relevance. Here is one of the links upon searching
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html

Comment: `Histogram` and `LBP histogram` are a bit more related to each other than `car` and `carpet`, but the link above is completely useless in this context

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems that, you are using 8-neighborhood LBP with radius r=1. So you can get maximum 256(2^8) number of different values. To construct Histogram, declare a matrix containing single row and 256 columns(bins) and initialize it with 0 :-

```
Mat H(1,256,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0));
```

Now for each central pixel ( pixels not in border ) ,after applying LBP you will get a binary string of length 8, and it's decimal encoding ( stored in `center_lbp` variable in your code segment ) represents corresponding bin of the histogram. So after calculating `center_lbp` just increment the value into the corresponding bin of the histogram as follows :-

> H.at`<uchar>`(center_lbp)+=1;

After parsing the image for each central pixel, you will get a LBP histogram for that image.

**LBP With Uniform Patterns :-**

A LBP is called uniform if the circular binary pattern ( clockwise ) contains maximum 2 transition from 0 to 1 and vice versa . For Ex:- 00111000 is uniform pattern but 10111000 is not. To construct LBP Histogram for uniform pattern, the rule is -

- Each uniform pattern has a it's unique bin in the histogram.
- All non uniform pattern will put into a single bin in the histogram.

for p number of neighbouring points, we can get maximum p*(p-1)+2 number of uniform patterns. So the histogram for uniform pattern will contain p*(p-1)+3 number of bins.

To construct the histogram :-

- get binary pattern for each central pixel by applying LBP on it.
- check whether the pattern is uniform or not.
- if uniform, then increment bin value in the reserved bin for this pattern of histogram by 1 . 
  you must have some mapping criteria to map a uniform pattern in the unique bin of the histogram.
- else it is a non-uniform pattern. So increment bin value in the reserved bin( Ex.- the last bin ) for all non uniform pattern of the histogram by 1 .

Comment: I did go through all this stuff...but I'm stuck at how to create a lookup table...do i need to write down all the 256 8-bit combinations and search for them manually?? 
Please help out....i am learning all this...

thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do this. Another way is, create a array which will contain decimal encoded value of uniform patterns only. whenever u get a LBP pattern, search the array, if found return the array index which is the mapped index in histogram for that uniform pattern. if not found then it is a non-uniform pattern. you can create the array statically or through some program for any arbitrary P.